# Discord Bot Update: How to play audio?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So recently the new version of the discord bot API came out for Node along with interactions and all that. And, they also changed some other stuff, don't know why. but they did.

I was trying to just try out the audio playing code to see how it works and maybe update some of my older bots, when I ran into the issue that it just doesn't work. I've been following the docs at https://discordjs.guide/voice/voice-connections.html#life-cycle and https://discordjs.guide/voice/audio-player.html#life-cycle but they're really just not working.

Just testing code looks like this:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const {token} = require("./config.json");
const { join } = require("path");
const {joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource, AudioPlayerStatus, VoiceConnectionStatus, SubscriptionStatus, StreamType  } = require("@discordjs/voice");
 
 
client.on("ready", async () => {
    const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
        channelId: channel.id,
        guildId: channel.guild.id,
        adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
    });
  

    const audioPlayer = createAudioPlayer();

    const resource = createAudioResource(createReadStream(join(__dirname, "plswork.mp3")));
    
    
    const subscription = connection.subscribe(audioPlayer);
    
    audioPlayer.play(resource);

    audioPlayer.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Playing, () => {
        console.log("currently playing");
        console.log("resource started:", resource.started);
    });
    
    audioPlayer.on('error', error => {
        console.error(`Error: ${error.message} with resource ${error.resource.metadata.title}`);
    });

    audioPlayer.on(AudioPlayerStatus.AutoPaused, () => {
        console.log("done?");
        
    });
```

I create a connection, audioPlayer, and resource but after subscribing the connection to the audioPlayer and playing the resource no audio is played, no error is raised (in `AudioPlayer.on("error"...)`) and the `AutoPaused` status is immediately called.

By logging the resource I see that `resource.playbackDuration` is 0, but I don't know how to fix this as I can't find much on the internet about this topic.

Comment: Can you please provide the console log?

Comment: Also, do you `require` the `AudioPlayerStatus`?
E.g.:
`const { VoiceConnectionStatus, AudioPlayerStatus } = require('@discordjs/voice');
`

Comment: I do require it, yes. And what do you want the log of? I'll get working on including everything

Comment: I didn't meant the json, I meant the console output that you recieve when running the bot. To be clear: where you get the output from `console.log("currently playing")`.

Comment: And, please, try [avoid using pastebin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339451/10301322) for this small amount of code

Comment: @CcmU The output at `console.log("currently playing");` would be `currently playing\n true`. if that's what you're asking

Comment: Yes, I know that, I was asking you to provide the entire output of your console, to see if there is any error. I guess it does not print only "currently playing", does it?

Comment: Btw, have you checked your bot permission, it could be that of the missing voice-related permission, I am using similar codes, and turns out I didn't enable the voice permission.

Comment: do you have all intents in your client? `["GUILD_VOICE_STATES", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILDS"]`

Comment: Did you found a solution? Have the same problem.

Comment: No, I never found the solution. When I saw all the music bots going down I started to suspect discord might be trying to prevent YouTube from getting upset by limiting user access to playing audio. But really I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell by looking at your code you are not requiring the correct json from `@discordjs/voice`, you need to require at least `AudioPlayerStatus` and `createAudioPlayer`. Also, by your `resource` I think you're trying to create an `AudioResource`, so you'll need it as well. You'll need something like:

```js
const { AudioPlayerStatus, createAudioPlayer, AudioResource, StreamType } = require('@discordjs/voice');
/* */
const audioPlayer = createAudioPlayer();
/* */
audioPlayer.play(resource);

audioPlayer.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Playing, () => {
        // Do whatever you need to do when playing
});
/* */
```

In conclusion, I suggest you to look up the [life cycle of an AudioPlayer](https://discordjs.guide/voice/life-cycles.html#life-cycles) and the [creation of an AudioPlayer](https://discordjs.guide/voice/audio-player.html#creation). Be sure, also, to create correctly your `resource`, [here](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/classes/audioresource.html) you'll find the `AudioResource` documentation if you'll ever need it.